# SoapUI - validation error java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlError

Tags: java, soap, soapui

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsrl="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/rl-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns1="http://workflow.comarch.com/SDService_ws" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsrp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/rp-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <soap:Body wsu:Id="myBody-1491835424">
      <ns1:listProcessesResponse>
         <listProcessesReturn xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="tns:listProcessesReturn"/>
      </ns1:listProcessesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What is wrong with that SOAP response? I'm using SoapUI to verify SOAP Answers. It checks if received response is compatible with WSDL standards. So when I run validation in SoapUI it produces the following error.

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlError

[image: Here it is shown on the screen]

Comment: Why is this tagged `perl`?

Comment: Because it's a webservice written in Perl.

Comment: Have you tried to contact your team or application provider to see if it is possible application defect?

Answer (score 2):

The message itself looks like a bug in SoapUI's error handling

> What is wrong with that SOAP response?

Your `schemaLocation` is wrong

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
```

you have the same URI in there twice

Also, you are using the namespace `tns` without having defined it in

```
xsi:type="tns:listProcessesReturn"
```

Comment: The above comment is wrong. The tns namespace is defined is WSDL which I loaded to SoapUI.